# move a pixel in Jframe and crash JFrame when use Thread.Sleep(1000)

Tags: java, swing, crash, jframe

I want to move a pixel in a JFrame but use of Thread.Sleep(1000) method eventuate to crash my JFrame. why this problem happen? and how solve it?
Thank You

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Sadra Graphics");
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    SadraGraphics sadraGraphics = new  SadraGraphics();
    sadraGraphics.setPreferredSize((new Dimension(640,480)));
    mainFrame.getContentPane().add( sadraGraphics );
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);    }}


public class SadraGraphics extends JPanel {


public void paintComponent (Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.white);

    for (int i = 0; i <=639; i++) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine(i, i * 3 / 4, i, i * 3 / 4);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawLine(i,i*3/4,i,i*3/4);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Post a runnable example. 2) _"and how solve it?"_ Don't use `Thread.sleep`

Comment: 1 : Ok    -   2: so  how to move my pixel !?

Comment: Use a `javax.swing.Timer`. And whatever you do **don't** put it in the `paintComponent` method

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use `Thread.sleep`. Even if you were to use it, you *never* want to use it in the `paintComponent` method.
2. Instead use a `javax.swing.Timer`, that will update some variables and repaint every so many milliseconds

   ```
   public SadraGraphics() {
       Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               // do something here that will refresh some variables that you
               // are using to paint, then call repaint()
               repaint();
           }
       });
       timer.start();
   }
   ```

See more at [**How to use Swing Timers**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Here a simple runnable example

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Sadra Graphics");
                mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                SadraGraphics sadraGraphics = new SadraGraphics();
                sadraGraphics.setPreferredSize((new Dimension(640, 480)));
                mainFrame.getContentPane().add(sadraGraphics);
                mainFrame.pack();
                mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class SadraGraphics extends JPanel {

    int x1 = 0;
    int y1 = 50;
    int x2 = 0;
    int y2 = 200;

    public SadraGraphics() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(30, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                x1 += 2;
                x2 += 2;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    }
}
```

---

**Side Note**

- Run Swing apps from the EDT using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.
- `paintComponent` should be `protected` not `public`
- Don't set the background from with the `paintComonent` method. You can either do it from the constructor or instead you can paint the background in the `paintComponent` method by doing this

  ```
  g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
  ```